# Root route is ignored when I add /admin route in FlowRouter

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

My home route works when it's by itself:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  triggersEnter: [
    function(context, redirect) {
      var ExperimentsSub, handle, randomExperiment;
      console.log('Home triggers');
      ExperimentsSub = new SubsManager;
      handle = ExperimentsSub.subscribe('randomExperiment');
      if (handle.ready && Experiments.find.count) {
        randomExperiment = Experiments.findOne;
        return redirect('/experiment/' + randomExperiment._id);
      }
    }
  ],
  action: function() {
    console.log('Rendering home');
    return BlazeLayout.render('layout', {
      content: 'home'
    });
  }
});
```

But when I add in my `/admin` route, surfing to `/` routes through the admin route instead.

```
FlowRouter.route('/admin', {
  name: 'admin',
  triggersEnter: [console.log('Admin triggers'), !Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin']) ? FlowRouter.go(FlowRouter.path('login')) : void 0],
  action: function() {
    console.log('Rendering admin');
    return BlazeLayout.render('layout', {
      content: 'admin'
    });
  }
});
```

I know this because of the console logging I'm doing. When I surf to `/` with both routes, the console output is `Rendering admin`. Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my admin route triggers. I was not assigning an array of functions. I'm not clear why this created the side effects I saw, but correcting it fixed the route.

The route with the fixed triggers property looks like this:

```
FlowRouter.route '/admin',
  name: 'admin'
  triggersEnter: [ (context, redirect) ->
    console.log 'Admin triggers'
    unless Roles.userIsInRole this.userId, ['admin']
      redirect FlowRouter.path('login')
  ]
  action: ->
    console.log 'Rendering admin'
    BlazeLayout.render 'layout', content: 'admin'
```